# ObjectiveC - Key-Value-Pair Collection with duplicate Keys

Tags: objective-c, collections

Does ObjectiveC provide a collection for Key-Value-Pairs, that allow a key to occur multiple times?

I try to parse a xml file into some simple structure. Every things is already working with nested NSDictionary, but now xml elements can occur multiple times.

Edit: My Solution

I choose an NSArray with KeyValuePairs, it turned out that I need something that is order sensitive, NSDictionary was not possible. Sideeffect: NSFastEnumeration is easy to implement this way for my collection.

Comment: I used the accepted answer first, but later (some days) it turned out that it wasn't possible. If I wouldn't have these conditions, I would use the solution of Sven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cocoa doesn’t have such a collection. If you don’t want to use a third-party library for that you can simulate that by using a `NSDictionary` with `NSArray` values. Or you could take a look at the [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) framework.

Comment: for those of you setting multiple GET parms with AFHTTPClient, it will handle just that if you set the value with an NSArray

Comment: Thanks @MaxMacLeod. I found the AFN behavior which appends "[]" to the repeated parameter name undesirable, but a quick edit fixes that: https://gist.github.com/4113874

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't be a very good key....

Best thing is to have an NSDictionary and for each key an NSArray holding all values against that key.

Answer (score 1):

Or an NSArray holding as many NSDictionaries (or NSObjects each with a key and a value property) as you like. You will then be able to filter the array with a predicate to find all the occurrences of a particular key and their associated values.